Hibernate envers : StrictJpaComplianceViolation: Encountered FQN entity name
If I set hibernate.jpa.compliance.query=true then I get :
org.hibernate.query.sqm.StrictJpaComplianceViolation: Encountered FQN entity name [gbt.osmoze.model.osmoze.audit.CustomRevEntity], but strict JPQL compliance was requested ( [CustomRevEntity] should be used instead )

Request is :
org.hibernate.envers.AuditReader reader;
Long id;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Object[]> list = reader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(clazz, false, true)
    .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))
    .getResultList();

With a custom revision entity :
package gbt.osmoze.model.osmoze.audit
@Entity
@Table(name="Revision_Infos")
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
public class CustomRevEntity implements Serializable, RevEntity {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @Column(name="revision_id")
  @RevisionNumber
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "RevisionInfosSequence")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "RevisionInfosSequence", sequenceName = "Revision_Infos_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
  private long revisionId;

  @Column(name="epoch_timestamp")
  @RevisionTimestamp
  private long epochTimestamp;

  @Convert(converter=gbt.model.converter.TimestampToInstantConverter.class)
  @Column(name="timestamp")
  private Instant timestamp;

  @Column(name="user_id")
  private String userId;

  // rest omitted
}

If hibernate.jpa.compliance.query=false then it works fine and the query is :
SELECT o1_0.REV,
       o1_0.ordre_operation_id,
       o1_0.ordre_operation_type,
       o1_0.REVTYPE,
       o1_0.cancelled_by_operation_id,
       o1_0.comment,
       o1_0.comment_source,
       c1_0.revision_id,
       c1_0.epoch_timestamp,
       c1_0.timestamp,
       c1_0.user_id
FROM Ordre_Operations_AUD o1_0,
     Revision_Infos c1_0
WHERE o1_0.ordre_operation_id=?
  AND o1_0.REV=c1_0.revision_id
ORDER BY o1_0.REV

So is it possible to work with Envers with hibernate.jpa.compliance.query set to true ?
I work with wildfly-29.0.1.Final and hibernate-envers 6.2.6.Final

Same problem if you use org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity and schema-generation "drop-and-create". Looks like you have to set hibernate.jpa.compliance.query to false.

I think that behavior is caused by envers internally generating HQL which uses the fully qualified class names of the entities which apparently does not conform with hibernate.jpa.compliance.query=true

That's unfortunate.
